# What software was used for these schematic diagrams?

Tags: software

I have several diagrams that I attached to this post. Does anyone know what software was used to make them? I attached the diagrams as PNG files but in PDF files that I have, they are in vector graphics.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: Are you sure it was a specific software package? They look suspiciously like hand-drawn bitmap images ("pixel art") to me.

Comment: I don't know which package I'm afraid but I've seen a lot of mid-1980's to (maybe) early 1990's schematics in this style. Could your schematic be that old?

Comment: @duskwuff, there must be a software package for this. It is all in vector graphics. All diagrams have very reproducible objects. I have access to hundreds of these diagrams and they all look alike. Drawing it all by hand would be insanely hard.

Comment: @TonyM, I think you are correct. I just checked the archive and saw that most of these schematics are from the 90's. Do you know what software was used back then to make such diagrams?

Comment: They look like AutoCAD drawings to me.

Comment: All in vector graphic? What is the file extension?

Comment: @Antonio. It is saved as a PDF. Unfortunately, I can't share the documents.

Comment: @SteveG, thanks! Could you please show me an example of an AutoCAD diagram that looks very close to these above? I will try to check tomorrow if AutoCAD produces such diagrams.

Comment: Does the PDF file happen to have any relevant information in its properties? (A PDF viewer should be able to show you.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I checked several files now. They seem to have "Acrobat Distiller 4.05 for Windows" as producer. One publication has "Corel Office Document" as its title.

Comment: @ViacheslavPlotnikov Aha! It could be that Corel Draw was used with an electronic symbols library.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, you just solved this! I didn't even think that Corel Draw can be used for schematic diagrams. Please write an answer for this post and I will mark it as "correct". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The presence of "Corel Office Document" in the properties of one of the PDF documents suggests that Corel Draw was used to produce them.

Electronic symbols libraries are available for Corel Draw.

The presence of "Acrobat Distiller 4.05 for Windows" might mean that Acrobat Distiller was then used to shrink some of the PDFs and/or make them more generally compatible with PDF readers.